# PyQt5 шрифты на разных ОС

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, шрифты, pyqt

Вопрос начинающего.
Пишется некая программа для Raspberry.
Используется PyQt5.
Сама разработка ведётся под виндой.

Вопрос. Задаю я для QLabel шрифт.
Потом запускаю прогу на Raspberry, а там-то такого шрифта нет.
Просветите, как обеспечить переносимость?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вижу тут следующие варианты:

- Не изменять семейство шрифтов [QFont::setFamily](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#setFamily), пусть будет использоваться текущий системный шрифт. Если хочется поменять размер, начертание и прочее, то работать с текущим, например:

  ```
  font = label.font()
  font.setPixelSize(20)
  font.setBold(True)
  label.setFont(font)
  ```
- Устанавливать семейство шрифтов, что есть на целевых ОС
- Таскать с собой шрифт. Через вызов [QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#addApplicationFont) добавлять файлы шрифтов в приложение и тогда их семейство может быть выбрано.

  О форматах:

  > Currently only TrueType fonts, TrueType font collections, and OpenType
  >   fonts are supported.

  Пример:

  ```
  from PyQt5.QtGui import QFontDatabase
  ...
  QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont('<путь до .ttf>')
  ```